# Как использовать ReceiveAsync в xamarin?

Tags: java, c#, .net, udp, xamarin

Вот пример использования udpclient из .net

```
  private static void UDPListener()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(11000))
        {
            string loggingEvent = "";
            while (true)
            {
                //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                loggingEvent += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults.Buffer);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Хотелось бы понять как использовать аналог из Java.Net.DatagramSocket.ReceiveAsync
[Увы почти пустое описание](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AJava.Net.DatagramSocket.ReceiveAsync(Java.Net.DatagramPacket))
Если не пример,то логику хотя бы

Comment: Думаю, что эта функция — просто асинхронный аналог [`Receive`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aJava.Net.DatagramSocket.Receive). То есть принимает данные в `pack`. (В документации описан аргумент `DatagramPacket pack`, у вас в коде его почему-то нету.)

Comment: @VladD '    Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                socket.Broadcast = true;
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.Length);
             
                while (true)
                {
                    await socket.ReceiveAsync(packet);
                    if (packet != null)
                    {
                        message mess = new message(packet);
                        
                    }
                }
            });'

Comment: Ну, тогда судя по всему `socket.ReceiveAsync(packet)` запускает обычный под`Task`, который асинхронно ожидает получения данных, и доставляет их в `packet`.

Comment: @VladD Только что-то эти данные не доходят( http://pastebin.com/Nci4dETy

Comment: Может быть, пакет приходит неполный? Имеет право, по идее. Если это так, вам надо собирать данные по пакетам, пока не дойдёт сколько необходимо. Попробуйте залогировать приход информации (или пройдите в отладчике, если возможно).

Comment: @VladD Не уверен что знаю как это сделать... не могу уловить как вообще правильно сделать чтобы параллельно ловить все сообщения, а там я бы уже в observable collection их сливал и по приходу выводил бы

Comment: Ну, это вы должны знать, какого размера вы ожидаете данные. Длину данных в пакете узнать можно.